# swift package manager for library that uses libxml

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I'm adding support for the Swift Package Manager to an [Obj-C library](https://github.com/pocketsvg/pocketsvg) that depends on `libxml`.

I notice the `Package.swift` file requires me to specify a package's URL, but what if the package is already on the system?

Here's my `Package.swift` file:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "PocketSVG",
)
```

If I run `$ swift build` I get:

`fatal error: 'libxml/xmlreader.h' file not found`

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a system library, you need to provide a system module package. For more information see also [Require System Libraries](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#require-system-libraries) in the SwiftPM documentation.

As an example system module package for libxml is [this one](https://github.com/timburgess/Clibxml2).