# Swift package manager ("Swift Build") compiles fine in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, swift-package-manager

When trying to install stencil via package manager it complains about some existing source files in my project importing module libxml2.

Although the library is linked correctly and compiles fine in xcode.

Can some one explain what im doing wrong?

Below is my console output

```html
MacBook-Pro:XCUI-ReportGen zaid$ swift build -Xcc -fblocks -Xswiftc -I/usr/local/include -Xlinker -L/usr/local/lib
Fetching https://github.com/kylef/Stencil.git
Fetching https://github.com/kylef/PathKit.git
Fetching https://github.com/kylef/Spectre.git
Cloning https://github.com/kylef/Spectre.git
Resolving https://github.com/kylef/Spectre.git at 0.7.2
Cloning https://github.com/kylef/Stencil.git
Resolving https://github.com/kylef/Stencil.git at 0.8.0
Cloning https://github.com/kylef/PathKit.git
Resolving https://github.com/kylef/PathKit.git at 0.8.0
Compile Swift Module 'Spectre' (8 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'PathKit' (1 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Stencil' (19 sources)
/Users/zaid/XCUI-ReportGen/.build/checkouts/Stencil.git-7635584243355970173/Sources/Context.swift:46:25: warning: expression implicitly coerced from 'Any?' to Any
    return dictionaries.popLast()
                        ^~~~~~~
/Users/zaid/XCUI-ReportGen/.build/checkouts/Stencil.git-7635584243355970173/Sources/Context.swift:46:25: note: provide a default value to avoid this warning
    return dictionaries.popLast()
                        ^~~~~~~
                                ?? <#default value#>
/Users/zaid/XCUI-ReportGen/.build/checkouts/Stencil.git-7635584243355970173/Sources/Context.swift:46:25: note: force-unwrap the value to avoid this warning
    return dictionaries.popLast()
                        ^~~~~~~
                               !
/Users/zaid/XCUI-ReportGen/.build/checkouts/Stencil.git-7635584243355970173/Sources/Context.swift:46:25: note: explicitly cast to Any with 'as Any' to silence this warning
    return dictionaries.popLast()
                        ^~~~~~~
                                as Any
/Users/zaid/XCUI-ReportGen/.build/checkouts/Stencil.git-7635584243355970173/Sources/Loader.swift:55:14: warning: no calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression
      return try environment.templateClass.init(templateString: content, environment: environment, name: name)
             ^
/Users/zaid/XCUI-ReportGen/.build/checkouts/Stencil.git-7635584243355970173/Sources/Loader.swift:68:18: warning: no calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression
          return try environment.templateClass.init(templateString: content, environment: environment, name: templateName)
                 ^
Compile Swift Module 'XCUIReportGenerator' (13 sources)
/Users/zaid/XCUI-ReportGen/XCUIReportGenerator/ExternalLibs/Fuzi/Document.swift:23:8: error: no such module 'libxml2'
import libxml2
       ^
/Users/zaid/XCUI-ReportGen/XCUIReportGenerator/ExternalLibs/Fuzi/Document.swift:23:8: error: no such module 'libxml2'
import libxml2
       ^
/Users/zaid/XCUI-ReportGen/XCUIReportGenerator/ExternalLibs/Fuzi/Document.swift:23:8: error: no such module 'libxml2'
import libxml2
       ^
/Users/zaid/XCUI-ReportGen/XCUIReportGenerator/ExternalLibs/Fuzi/Document.swift:23:8: error: no such module 'libxml2'
import libxml2
       ^
/Users/zaid/XCUI-ReportGen/XCUIReportGenerator/ExternalLibs/Fuzi/Document.swift:23:8: error: no such module 'libxml2'
import libxml2
       ^
/Users/zaid/XCUI-ReportGen/XCUIReportGenerator/ExternalLibs/Fuzi/Document.swift:23:8: error: no such module 'libxml2'
import libxml2
       ^
/Users/zaid/XCUI-ReportGen/XCUIReportGenerator/ExternalLibs/Fuzi/Document.swift:23:8: error: no such module 'libxml2'
import libxml2
       ^
/Users/zaid/XCUI-ReportGen/XCUIReportGenerator/ExternalLibs/Fuzi/Document.swift:23:8: error: no such module 'libxml2'
import libxml2
       ^
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): /Applications/Xcode8.3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /Users/zaid/XCUI-ReportGen/.build/debug.yaml
```

[Link to the output from my debug.yaml run](http://textuploader.com/dr1rd)

Comment: I do not see a single question mark punctuation in this question (or in the title).  So... what's the question?

Comment: My question is am i doing something wrong when trying to install stencil via package manager ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use libxml. This is a C library, and without the required wrapper library it will not build in Swift. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206724/swift-package-manager-for-library-that-uses-libxml).